# Faild to get lock in SVNRDUMP Load

Tags: svn, load, dump, svn-repository

I want to move svn folder to another svn folder. I used dump in old svn folder. After that I used svnrdump load to another svn folder. They are same machine different svn repo. During the load, I cut off with Ctr+C. After that I tried to load again. But the following error is returning.

```
> Failed to get lock on destination repos, currently held by 'current computer name'  
> svnrdump: E200015: Caught signal  
> svnrdump: E200042:
> Additional errors: svnrdump: E200015: Caught signal
```

Here is my code of svn.

```
svnrdump dump http://...... > C:/mydump
svnrdump load http://.......< C:/mydump
```

How can I solve this? Thanks all

Comment: Do (did) you use `svnsync`? If yes you should run `svn propdel svn:sync-lock --revprop -r 0 YOURREPO`.

Comment: Thanks uzsolt. It seems okay.

Comment: Hello Uzsolt. I have loaded dump file to svn. but i found log. But there is no file. Is there anything to do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: So the `dump` and `load` was okay?

Comment: No. It is sill showing failed to get lock error

Comment: When? At `load` or `dump`?

Comment: It is in load. sorry for delay. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete `svn:rdump-lock` on destination:

```
svn propdel svn:rdump-lock --revprop -r 0 DESTINATION
```

But in this case if you want `svnrdump load` agian you'll get another error message (similar to follow):

```
svnrdump: E160020: File already exists: filesystem '62fb10e7-eabe-e711-825a-005056a07bed', transaction '4-5', path '/trunk'
```

I didn't find other solution than:

```
svn checkout FAILED_DESTINATION failed_dest
cd failed_dest
svn rm *
svn commit . -m "restart load"
svnrdump load FAILED_DESTINATION < full.dump
```

If you can `ssh` into `FAILED_DESTINATION` maybe can try `svnadmin load -r LAST_SUCCESS_REV:HEAD < dumpfile`. The `svnrdump` doesn't support `-r` option. But I think in this case (able to `ssh`) simplier to delete the partial repository and create a new one and do `svnrdump load` again.

I'm not subversion-expert and I don't have any (better) idea.